# Automatic subsetting of a dataframe on the basis of a prediction matrix

Tags: r, matrix, subset, r-mice

I have created a prediction matrix for large dataset as follows:

```
library(mice)
dfpredm <- quickpred(df, mincor=.3)

    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
A   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0
B   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1
C   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
D   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
E   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
**F 0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0**
G   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
H   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
I   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0
J   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

I would like to create a subset of the original df on the basis on `dfpredm`.

More specifically I would like to do the following:

Let's assume that my dependent variable is `F`.
According to the prediction matrix F is correlated with C and G.
In addition, C and G are best predicted by D,E and B,D respectively.

The idea is now to create a subset of `df` based on the dependent variable F,for which in the `F` row the value is 1.

```
Fpredictors <- df[,(dfpredm["F",]) == 1]
```

But also do the same for the variables where the rows in `F` are 1. I am thinking of first getting the column names like this:

```
Fpredcol <-colnames(dfpredm[,(dfpredm["c241",]) == 1])
```

And then doing a `for loop` with these column names?

For the specific example I would like to end up with the subset.

```
dfsub <- df[,c("F","C","G","B","E","D")]
```

I would however like to automate this process. Could anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one strategy that seems like it would work for you:

```
first_preds <- function(dat, predictor) {
  cols <- which(dat[predictor, ] == 1)
  names(dat)[cols]
}

# wrap first_preds() for getting best and second best predictors
first_and_second_preds <- function(dat, predictor) {
  matches <- first_preds(dat, predictor)
  matches <- c(matches, unlist(lapply(matches, function(x) first_preds(dat, x))))
  c(predictor, matches) %>% unique()
}

dat[first_and_second_preds(dat, "F")] # order is not exactly the same as your output

  F C G D E B
A 1 1 0 1 0 1
B 0 0 1 0 1 0
C 0 0 0 1 1 0
D 1 1 0 0 0 0
E 1 0 1 1 0 1
F 0 1 1 0 0 0
G 0 0 0 1 0 1
H 1 1 0 0 0 0
I 0 0 1 1 1 1
J 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Not sure if the ordering in the result is important, but you could add the logic if it is.

Using `dat` from here (a kinder way to share small R data on SO):

```
dat <- read.table(
  text = "A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
  A   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0
  B   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1
  C   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
  D   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
  E   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
  F   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
  G   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
  H   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
  I   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0
  J   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0",
  header = TRUE
)
```

Something a little more general that would let you use `self_select` predictors directly:

```
all_preds <- function(dat, predictors) {
  unlist(lapply(predictors, function(x) names(dat)[which(dat[x, ] == 1 )]))
}

dat[all_preds(dat, c("A", "B"))]

  B C D F H I A E G J
A 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
B 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
C 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
D 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
E 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
F 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
G 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
H 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
I 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nate! Code looks really nice! I immediately tried to see if it works. However the result is `[1] NA` for some reason. Is there anything I could have done wrong?

Comment: I tried `first_preds` by itself, but then the result is `NULL`.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird I run `first_preds(dat, "F")` and get `"C" "G"`. Hard to say what it could be, maybe restart your R-session?

Comment: Okay I solved it. The problem was that my prediction matrix was actually a matrix. I converted it to a dataframe and then it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey Nate, I have one more small question. I played around with your solution and realised that  in some cases I should probably determine the first round of predictors myself (because I obviously should have know that correlation is not everything). I noticed that I could replace `first_preds(dat, predictor)` by a character vector? that I would self select i.e : `selfselect <- c("A", "B")`, but I would rather feed this to the last line instead of "F". How can I make you solution accept: `dat[first_and_second_preds(dat, selfselect)]`?

Comment: @Tom added something that I think will let you pass in secondary predictors directly

Comment: You are a live saver @Nate. I tried it, and it works. The only thing is that it no longer has unique columns (creating a loooot of columns). I have tried to incorporate the `unique` section from your previous answer, but I have failed miserably.

Comment: Not sure if I totally follow, perhaps your idea of adding a call to `unique(unlist(....))` would resolve it?

Comment: It did, thank you so much! You have really been a ton of help!

Comment: Glad to hear, that's what this place is about, happy coding!

Comment: Hey Nate! I am trying to use your solution (the all_preds one) on a list of dataframes. I have tried something like: `predvars = ls()` and then `predvars[[i]]=dat[[i]][all_preds(dat[[i]] , dfsubsetvars)]` .  But it says `Error in ... replacement has length zero`. Would you be able to tell me the right syntax?

Comment: do you really mean `ls()` that would list everything in your R environment. are the `predictors` the same for each data frame in your list or do those change with each one?

Comment: I feel so stupid.. I just two seconds ago figured out that `ls()` is not `list()`. It does actually work now.. I have been spending hours on this issue haha.. In any case, thank you for your super quick response.. On to the next problem ;)